# Building a RAID5 out of multiple drives

Tags: hard-drive, raid, software-raid, lvm

I have 2x 12TB drives and then these three additional drives: 2TB, 3TB, 3TB

I want to create a RAID5 with as much capacity as I can. So, I was wondering if it'd be possible to use the three small drives (2,3,3) in a LVM and create a 8TB logical partition with it. Then add that logical partition to the RAID, which would look like this:

- 8TB (12TB drive)
- 8TB (12TB drive)
- 8TB (2TB+3TB+3TB drives)

this would give me a 16TB capacity

Comment: This sounds doable, although I'm not making this a full "answer" as I'm not providing the LVM-specific details. However, just like RAID 10 (a.k.a. RAID 1+0) is essentially a RAID 1 made of up RAID 0 storage devices (instead of a RAID 1 made up of hard drives), this proposition is essentially a RAID 5 made up of 3 data storage devices, which are two hard drives and one RAID 0 (or JBOD/etc.) device. Sort of like a RAID 50, but the lower layer is not fully RAID 0, just part of it is.  So long as LVM supports nested RAID, this will likely work (theoretically, even if not ideally performant speed).

Comment: TOOGAM is correct, this is doable.  However, I would say its a little silly.  Its overly complicated, when you can just mirror the two 12TB drives and have a 12TB RAID 1.  Or buy another 12TB and have 24TB RAID 5.

Comment: Thank you both.